# как браузер использует URL в DOCTYPE

Tags: html, xhtml

Зачем при объявлении DOCTYPE указывать URL? Что браузер дальше делает с этой информацией? Если открыть URL например http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd, то получим некий xml файл (или dtd файл, лень смотреть что это). В этом файле весь текст является комментариями.

т.е. вряд ли браузер использует этот URL для получения в режиме реального времени некой информации о спецификации. Да и вряд ли все браузеры перед открытием страниц идут по этому URL за справочной информацией. Да в режиме отсутствия интернета они вполне отображают страницы.

Или в браузере есть локальная информация о содержимом .dtd файла, а в этом файле действительно храниться необходимая для корректного отображения страницы инфа. И браузер раз в некий период просто обновляет .dtd в локальном кэше (но все равно, зачем тогда в DOCTYPE этот URL писать).

И раз уж об этом спрашиваю, когда указываю xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", что с этой информацией делает браузер? Он лезет по ссылке?

Comment: В html5 не требуется указывать ни один url

Comment: [Is the HTML Doctype URL downloaded by the client browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4758365/2881286)

Comment: @andreymal наверное стоило сказать сперва что это устарело, а не про html5

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь ну не совсем устарело, в xml-синтаксисе для html5 указывать такой xmlns по-прежнему требуется (впрочем, использовать xml-синтаксис никто не заставляет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу сам себе. Примерно то же что написали в комментариях.

Существует язык SGML, от которого пошли HTML, XML, XHTML, SVG и прочие. SGML является мета языком (т.е. языком шаблоном) и его реализации требуют наличие dtd файла, где описано какие именно теги могут быть и что в них содержится.

В xml (который является потомком SGML) так же использовали раньше dtd, но сейчас советуют использовать xml схемы. Однако для HTML до версии 5 и xhtml используются dtd файлы для описания конкретного языка разметки.

HTML 5 не базируется на SGML и не имеет dtd файла-описания в принципе (Вроде как HTML 5 не базируется на SGML но совместима с ним. т.е. это формально другой язык, но крайне похожий на предыдущие HTML). Поэтому для HTML 5 нет никакого dtd.

И к вопросу, "а что браузеры делают с этой ссылкой можно" можно прочитать англоязычную  вики https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration. Там сказано, что браузеры используют HTML парсеры, а не dtd парсеры общего назначения.

Т.е. по сути содержимое DOCTYPE для браузера является очень длинной константой, которую он не рассматривает в качестве отдельных элементов. Такие "навороты" у DOCTYPE появились из за того, что HTML по сути является приложением SGML, которое требует что бы в DOCTYPE была всякая всячина. Расшифровки содержимого DOCTYPE вроде

`<!DOCTYPE [Элемент верхнего уровня] [Публичность] "[Регистрация]//[Организация]//[Тип] [Имя]//[Язык]" "[URL]">`

не имеют смысла для браузеров и не парсятся ими.

Данные расшифровки могут быть полезны например для xml файлов, работающих в составе некой системы или иных SGML языков, где действительно определяется откуда для данного документа берется dtd файл в данный момент.

- возможно данное описание SGML и dtd не вполне коректно